# onSingleTapConfirmed method is not working

Tags: android, gesture, gesturelistener

My code is not working as I expected. Can someone help me? All I need is `GestureListener` to work. Thank you in advance.

```
package com.redevents.copd;

import android.support.v4.view.GestureDetectorCompat;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;


public class LastPage extends Activity implements Animation.AnimationListener {

private GestureDetectorCompat _detectorCompat;
private SqlDbHelper _sqlDbHelper;


Animation animation_page_two;
Animation animation_breathing_difficulties;
Animation animation_productive_cough;
Animation animation_poor_appetite;
Animation animation_dofilin;
Animation animation_exflem;
Animation animation_appebon;
Animation animation_green_bg;
Animation animation_group_fade_in;
Animation animation_we_med_thank_you;

final float volumeChange = 0.8f;
float volume = 1.0f;
int count, length;
boolean start, cheeringIsPlaying, coughingIsPlaying, applauseIsPlaying, coughingHasBeenPlayed, applauseHasBeenPlayed, applauseIncreasing;
boolean wtf = false;
boolean wth = false;
boolean jinde = false;

Context l_context;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    this._detectorCompat.onTouchEvent(event);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    /*if((animation_page_two.hasEnded() && count == 1) ||
            (animation_dofilin.hasEnded() && count == 2) ||
            (animation_exflem.hasEnded() && count == 3) ||
            (animation_appebon.hasEnded() && count == 4) ||
            (animation_group_fade_in.hasEnded() && count == 5)) {
        start = true;
        count++;

    }
    if (wth) {

        wth = false;
        count = 2;

    } else if (wtf) {
        wtf = false;
        count = 6;
        modal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        modal.setAnimation(animation_group_fade_in);
        rating_header.startAnimation(animation_group_fade_in);
        rating_bar_label.startAnimation(animation_group_fade_in);
        rating_bar.startAnimation(animation_group_fade_in);
        done.startAnimation(animation_group_fade_in);
    } else if(animation_we_med_thank_you.hasEnded() && count == 11 && jinde) {
        submit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        footnote.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        count++;
    }*/
}

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

}

/*@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

    if((animation_page_two.hasEnded() && count == 1) ||
            (animation_dofilin.hasEnded() && count == 2) ||
            (animation_exflem.hasEnded() && count == 3) ||
            (animation_appebon.hasEnded() && count == 4) ||
            (animation_group_fade_in.hasEnded() && count == 5)) {
        start = true;
        count++;

    }
    if (wth) {

        wth = false;
        count = 5;

    } else if (wtf) {
        wtf = false;
        count = 10;
        modal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        modal.setAnimation(animation_group_fade_in);
        rating_header.startAnimation(animation_group_fade_in);
        rating_bar_label.startAnimation(animation_group_fade_in);
        rating_bar.startAnimation(animation_group_fade_in);
        done.startAnimation(animation_group_fade_in);
    } else if(animation_we_med_thank_you.hasEnded() && count == 11 && jinde) {
        submit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        footnote.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        count++;
    }
}*/

private class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event) {
        if (start) {
            if (count >= 100) {
                count = 1;
                wth = true;
                //green_bg.startAnimation(animation_green_bg);
                x_mark.setEnabled(false);
            }
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+count, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            switch (count) {
                case 0:
                    x_mark.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    start = false;

                    //_playSounds(4);

                    cross_one.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            cross_two.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            count++;
                            start = true;
                        }
                    }, 500);

                    break;
                case 1:

                    x_mark.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    page_two.startAnimation(animation_page_two);
                    applauseIncreasing = true;

                    //_playSounds(5);

                    volume = 0.1f;
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            while (!Thread.interrupted() && (volume <= 1.0f) && applauseIncreasing) {
                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            volume = volume / volumeChange;
                                            sound_applause.setVolume(volume, volume);
                                        }
                                    });
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }).start();

                    break;
                case 2:
                    x_mark.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    dofilin.startAnimation(animation_dofilin);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    x_mark.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    exflem.startAnimation(animation_exflem);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    x_mark.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    appebon.startAnimation(animation_appebon);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    wtf = true;

                    green_bg.startAnimation(animation_green_bg);
                    //                        oNLastPage();
                    x_mark.setEnabled(false);

                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Please don't dump your whole code. Post only small-part that can explain the problem.

Comment: Where are you initializing `_detectorCompat`?

Comment: *How* is it "not working" and *how **should*** it work? Please don't expect us to figure out your intent from a big code sample, and then help with your problem. Explain your question as clearly as possible.